# How to sort table if value is itself a table

Tags: sorting, lua

How can I sort this table based on sequence value

```
Record['Personnel Number']={['sequence']=1, ['mapping']='data',['value']='employeeCode', ['decode']='', ['expression']=''}

Record['Effective Date']={['sequence']=3, ['mapping']='data', ['value']='payDate', ['decode']='', ['expression']=''}

Record['Unit']={['sequence']=4, ['mapping']='data', ['value']='payUnit', ['decode']='', ['expression']=''}

Record['Wage Type']={['sequence']=2, ['mapping']='data', ['value']='payCode', ['decode']='', ['expression']=''}
```

Comment: `Record` is not a list and so cannot be sorted. What output do you imagine?

Answer (score 2):

You can use table.sort to sort lists.

> `table.sort (list [, comp])`
>   Sorts list elements in a given order, in-place, from list[1] to list[#list].
>   If `comp` is given, then it must be a function that receives two list
>   elements and returns true when the first element must come before the
>   second in the final order

```
local comp = function(a,b) return a.sequence < b.sequence end
```

Would sort a list by the sequence value of it's element table.

You do not have a list. Lua tables key value pairs do not have an order. Hence you cannot sort.

Sorting a list is done by swapping values between numeric keys.

Answer (score 1):

If sequence values are unique and don't collide with existing keys, you can create an alternate index:

```
for k,v in pairs(Record) do
    if type(v) == "table" then
        Record[v.sequence] = v
        v.key = k -- optional
    end
end
```

Then,

1) You can index by sequence value

```
print(Record[4].key, Record[4].value)
```

2) If sequence values are also all integers, start at 1 and don't skip in the middle, you could use `ipairs` to iterate

```
for i,v in ipairs(Record) do
    print(i, v.key, v.value)
end
```